# Dash is not behaving normal in Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: unity-dash

There is a whitish rectangle in the left-bottom corner and the top-left corner is turning dark and blinking for a while when I click on something in dash.[image]
  It did not happen in Quantal or Precise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Steps:

1. For this you need to install CompizConfig Settings Manager
2. Then under CCSM go to Desktop -> Ubuntu Unity Plugin -> General -> Dash Blur
3. In that Dash Blur options set option as "No Blur"

That's it .